# How to check if the an item of an array has truthy value

Tags: javascript

In array of objects, how to check if any array item has truthy property

I have a array of objects, i need to check if any of array item has a property which value is trutly

```
const arr = [{name: 'Tony', test: false}, {name: 'Jack', test: false}, {name: 'Tina', test: false}]

const check = arr.filter(item =>item.test });
```

The code above is doing the job. check is an array of matched item or an empty array depending on the condition matched. I am wondering if I can do this in a better way. I just need check to be true if any item inside of arr has test property truthy or false if none of the items test property is truthy

Comment: do you want a single boolean?

Comment: arr.some(item => item.tes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and get a boolean value.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'Tony', test: false }, { name: 'Jack', test: false }, { name: 'Tina', test: false }],
    check = array.some(item => item.test);

console.log(check);
```

Comment: Just checking in to let people know about the complimentary function, [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)