# Is there a way to check for falsy values from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check a bunch of variables for falsy values.

Instead of writing a very long if statement, e.g.:

```
if (!userData.email || !userData.lastName || ! userData.firstName etc...
```

I wanted to put these values in an array and simply check the array, e.g.:

```
      var detailsConditionsArr = [
        userData.firstName,
        userData.lastName,
        userData.email,
        userData.phone,
        userData.address,
        userData.mailAddress,
      ]

      if (detailsConditionsArr.indexOf(false) === 1) {
        console.log("Found a falsy");
      }
```

But the above doesn't work (if statement never fires).

The values could be `false`, `null` or `''`.

Is there a way to check these from the array?

Comment: How about [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)?

Comment: Your condition for indexOf is wrong, your checking if there is a false value at index 1, so yes it's not working

Comment: You can achieve what you want with !(detailsConditionsArr.indexOf(false) === -1)

Comment: Ah you're right @NicolasMenettrier. Want to make that an answer?

Comment: @David the array syntax seems fine, there are no issues with it. Unless you're on an old and unsupported browser like IE7, for example.

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier - But value could be any falsy value, not necessarily `false`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the an item of an array has truthy value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426684/how-to-check-if-the-an-item-of-an-array-has-truthy-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideal use case for [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Check for falsy value in the iteration, if the test succeeds, `true` will be returned.

```js
var A = ["Name", ""];
var B = ["Name", "30"];
var C = ["Name", "30", null];

if (A.some(el => !el)) {
  console.log("Found a falsy in A");
}

if (B.some(el => !el)) {
  console.log("Found a falsy in B");
}

if (C.some(el => !el)) {
  console.log("Found a falsy in C");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the key names you want to check as an array, then do the check like this:

```js
const userData = { email: '', lastName: '', firstName: '' };
const hasFalsy = ['email', 'lastName', 'firstName'].some(k => !Boolean(userData[k]));

if (hasFalsy) {
  console.log('found a falsy');
}
```

Comment: I would upvote, but your code is incomplete, `userData is undefined`

Comment: @JeremyThille Ah, update the code with fake userData

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to return a single value from the array like so:

```
var detailsConditionsArr = [
    userData.firstName,
    userData.lastName,
    userData.email,
    userData.phone,
    userData.address,
    userData.mailAddress,
  ]

if (detailsConditionsArr.reduce((carry, el)=> el ? carry : true, false)) {
  console.log("Found a falsy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` method.

```js
          var detailsConditionsArr = [
            "test",
            12,
            false,
            "s",
            "sd",
            "test",
          ]
          
          if (detailsConditionsArr.some(x => !x)) {
            console.log("Found a falsy");
          }
         
         // or 
         //if (detailsConditionsArr.some(x => !Boolean(x))) {
         //   console.log("Found a falsy");
         //}
```

Comment: I'd prefer [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of every since we don't need to check more values if we've already found a falsy one.

Comment: Reyno is correct. If the array has one million elements and the first one is falsy, `some` will stop at the first element, but `every` will still examine all one million of them. This answer works, but it's not optimized

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the list of properties and then check if any is falsy :

```js
const userData = {
  firstName : 'John',
  lastName : 'Doe',
  email : null,
  phone : 42,
  address : 'Hello',
  mailAddress : 'world'
};

function HasObjectAnyFalsyValues(obj)
{
  for (let prop in obj)
  {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)
          && !obj[prop]) { // <-- check for falsy
          return true;
      }
  }
  
  return false;
}

console.log('The object has ' + (!HasObjectAnyFalsyValues(userData) ? 'no ' : '') + 'falsy values');
```

This will check **all properties**. If you want to list specific properties instead, use one of the other answers posted

Answer (score 0):

Using `some` is a clean way for doing this job.

The `Array.prototype.some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function (in your case, falsy value).

```js
 const userData = {};
  userData.firstName = "dd";
  userData.lastName = false;
  userData.email = 0;
  userData.phone = 123;
  userData.address = "aad";
  userData.mailAddress = "dff";
    
 const detailsConditionsArr = [
    userData.firstName,
    userData.lastName,
    userData.email,
    userData.phone,
    userData.address,
    userData.mailAddress,
  ]
  
 const detailsConditionsArr2 = [true, 1, "fff"];

 const doesHaveFalsy = obj => obj.some(x => !x);

 if (doesHaveFalsy(detailsConditionsArr)) {
   console.log("detailsConditionsArr Found a falsy");
 }
 
 if (doesHaveFalsy(detailsConditionsArr2)) {
   console.log("detailsConditionsArr2 Found a falsy");
 }
```

More about some - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some